# Monitoring Airflow health endpoints in AWS Cloudwatch

Tags: airflow, amazon-cloudwatch

How do I monitor the health endpoints in aws cloudwatch. Presumably a response code of 200 isn’t enough ie need to interrogate the JSON body for the metadatabase and scheduler.

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.1.0/logging-monitoring/check-health.html

Answer (score 0):

You can do it simply with AWS Lambda sending custom metrics to Cloudwatch.

In your Lambda you will need to:

1. Write code that will query the Airflow API health endpoint
2. Parse response end extract data as you wish
3. Prepare metric data based on endpoint response
4. Send metric to cloud watch check [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/publishingMetrics.html)

Then you need to schedule that lambda runs for desired metric granularity - check AWS docs [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/RunLambdaSchedule.html).

Comment: Thanks for that. I had thought of that but just wanted to explore any vanilla solutions ie just with CW. 

Eg it does mention in these docs where you can monitor the /health endpoint for ELBs and was therefore just 1 step away from then interrogating the response body. 

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-healthchecks.html